# Self creating singleton in every method. Is it bad?

Tags: php, optimization, resources, singleton

everybody! Here's a little singleton for registry pattern. Its very common.

```
class REG {
    private $_objects;  
    protected static $_instance;

    private function __construct() {}

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (self::$_instance === NULL) self::$_instance = new self();  
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    public static function set($name, $object) {
        self::$_instance->_objects[$name] = $object;
    }

    public static function get($name) {
        return self::$_instance->_objects[$name];
    }   

    public static function testMe() {
        return self::$_instance;
    }       

    private function __clone() {}
    private function __wakeup() {}    
}
```

Using it suppose that we should call `REG::getInstance()` first and then any desired method.

```
REG::getInstance();
REG::set('name','Denis');
var_dump(REG::testMe());
// object(REG)#1 (1) { ["_objects":"REG":private]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(5) "Denis" } }
```

Everything works fine! But... as i'm planning to use this class to store global variables for my project I obviously do not want to spend extra line every time when I need to access any global var inside func. In above example we can omit calling `REG::getInstance()` and will get no error when running script. The only difference will be that `self::$_instance` now will be an instance of stdClass

```
REG::set('name','Denis');
var_dump(REG::testMe());
// object(stdClass)#1 (1) { ["_objects"]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(5) "Denis" } }
```

In this particular case it makes no difference, but if we'll need some additional functionality of our class, this can become critical. 
Another way to avoid calling for `REG::getInstance()` is to put `if (self::$_instance === NULL) self::$_instance = new self();` line on every method of our class:

```
class REG {
    private $_objects;  
    protected static $_instance;

    private function __construct() {}

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (self::$_instance === NULL) self::$_instance = new self();  
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    public static function set($name, $object) {
        if (self::$_instance === NULL) self::$_instance = new self();  
        self::$_instance->_objects[$name] = $object;
    }

    public static function get($name) {
        if (self::$_instance === NULL) self::$_instance = new self();  
        return self::$_instance->_objects[$name];
    }   

    public static function testMe() {
        if (self::$_instance === NULL) self::$_instance = new self();  
        return self::$_instance;
    }       

    private function __clone() {}
    private function __wakeup() {}    
}
REG::set('name','Denis');
var_dump(REG::testMe());
// object(REG)#1 (1) { ["_objects":"REG":private]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(5) "Denis" } }
```

Now it's fine! 
So, the question I want to ask =) is there any unnoticed cons using this approach? Maybe some unwished resource overheads or something else?

PS: i've searched SO before asking this question, but didn't found an answer. Maybe it's because my English is not very good. Then please just point me right direction. 
Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: A magic funtion named __call will automatically run on every function you called. So, create a function named __call with the code that needs to execute every time.

Comment: Really? Shame to me... Thanks. But will it works on static class?

Comment: Have a look: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.callstatic

Comment: @silentboy =) 1:1 tnx!

Answer (score 0):

**May be someone is trying to kill an ant with hummer**
why you wont like my idea:

```
class REG {
public function data($name, $value=null){
if(!$value) return $this->{$name};
$this->{$name} = $value;
}
}
$bin = new REG();
$bin->data('working','no');
echo $bin->data('working');
```

**edit**

**You have hurt my object oriented mind**

well, you want to create a bucket to store your particles, Then make available it to every class of people.
But what if you store them in a bin then give it to one who needs it.
OOP comes with a idea of encapsulation. But singlton hurts it. Because your vars will globally available.
Another thing is OOP comes with an idea of good code reuseability.
But what if you create a class with some function called from singlton.  You need to use both singlton and your main class next time.

So, if you are determined to use singlton. Then its not so bad because many people use it.
But, ** i will recommend to pass your variable as parameter to your function that needs it.
Thanks for have time to read it. Again i am not so much experienced, i am just 17

Comment: if you'll read my post, you'll see that 

1 i'm trying to avoid adding extra line each time i need to get\set some var

2 i want to use singleton to be sure that i have same variables in any point of my project

Comment: Ok, if the shoes fit, wear it. But i think there should some performance problem in your code. Just bencmark to see the regult. I am currently havnt access to my pc.

Comment: That is exactly why i'm asking this question - my figure out about possible performance problems. =)
By the way, tnx for phrase "if the shoes fit, wear it", like it.

Comment: Generally I have nothing against dependency injection. I'm using it when dealing with any "subobjects" which are functional part of a project. But REG class is made only to store some global vars, it is kind of config storage. So I won't "create a class with some function called from singlton". The only purpose of this class is to store config data and to provide easy access to this data. I understand that this approach is not from classic OOP, but I don't see any serious reason to be strictly OOPed in this case. And what about you? interested to know your thoughts about it.